# A view in the website that can show only questions with tags I've subscribed to

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, filtering

I wish to be able to filter the entire list to see only questions with tags I've subscribed to. Is there a way to do it without tweaking with the search ? if not - I think it would be a nice addition.

I don't want to receive emails about them (well, maybe on some of them...)
maybe the site should have two level of subscription - show filter and email filter.
Just my thoughts.

Comment: See [Displaying only favorite tags on homepage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83787/164403) on the Overmeta.

Comment: I see there is a solution to my problem. a button to filter it would be nice, but I'll just add this link to my favorites bar.

Comment: Oh - one problem - the solution to that question doesn't work at all. I get all kind of tags, and not only mine. Or am I doing something wrong ? how can I see the list of tag that I've subscribe to ?